# Sort Action Should not Takes Place when i click the Checkbox in Table Header => Table Sorter

Tags: jquery, tablesorter

I used table Sorter for the Summary Screen, Here i Faced an Issue..

Consider my table header has checkbox in the first column and label in the other columns.

At the first time it is working fine.. After Sorting when i click the checkbox the table rows gets Sorted but it Should not..

When i click the Checkbox no sorting action should Happen.

Currently Using the 
[TABLE SORTER](http://tablesorter.com/docs/)

Help Me to solve this.!!!!

HTML :

```
<th data-sorter="false">
    <input id="hdr_ck_box" type="checkbox" class="hdr_ck_box" />
</th>
```

Comment: please share your code by which you added checkbox to the table and applied sorting to it.

Comment: <th data-sorter="false"><input id="hdr_ck_box" type="checkbox" class="hdr_ck_box" /></th>

Comment: can you please share jsfiddle link with your problem statement?

Answer (score 1):

Try this : bind click event for the checkbox and stop propagation of click event to the parent elements like below

**Note** - if you have already bind click event to checkbox then add `e.stopPropagation();` as first line in the code or if you are calling any function on click of checkbox then call it after `e.stopPropagation();` in below code.

```
$(function(){
  $('#hdr_ck_box').click(function(e){
      e.stopPropagation();
  });
});
```

Comment: +1 for the right idea, but if the user is using my [fork of tablesorter](http://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/), the event should be *"mouseup"* instead of click. Please refer to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25621660/tablesorter-can-not-click-pulldown-in-header) on using selects in the header.